# Discrete Mathematics Marble Probability Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A bag contains thirty marbles numbered from 1 to 30. Five marbles are drawn at random from the bag. There are a few ways to think about this:

a. Marbles are drawn one at a time without replacement. That is, once a marble is drawn, it is not replaced in the bag.

b. Marbles are drawn all at once without replacement. That is, five marbles are snatched up at once.

c. Marbles are drawn one at a time with replacement. Once a marble is drawn, it is tossed back into the bag. Then the next marble is drawn, tossed back in, and so on.
For each of these interpretations,

(i) Describe the sample space. How large is the set?

(ii) What is the probability that the marbles numbered 1 and 2 are not among those drawn from the bag?

(iii) What is the probability that at least one of the marbles numbered 16,17,18 are among the five marbles drawn from the bag?

- for the sample spaces I have:

A.) $P(30,5)$

B.) $C(30,5)$

C.) $30^5$

- for the probability of marbles 1 and 2 not being chosen I have:

A.) $\dfrac{P(28,5)}{P(30,5)}$

B.) $\dfrac{C(28,5)}{C(30,5)}$

C.) $\dfrac{28^5}{30^5}$

- and then for part (iii) I really have no idea

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: You have only given the sizes of the respective sample spaces. "Description" means you also have to provide the description of the *set* which serves as a sample space, not merely its size. However, the second part is fine.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

- either at least one of the marbles numbered 16,17,18 are among the five marbles drawn from the bag,
- or the marbles numbered 16, 17 and 18 are not among those drawn from the bag

and note that exactly one of the above events *must* occur. That is,
$$\Pr(\text{at least one of }16,17,18\text{ drawn})+\Pr(\text{none of }16,17,18\text{ drawn})=1\text{,}$$
for any of the scenarios.

Can you finish from here?